# Use Cygwin to tail multiple files

Tags: cygwin, tail

I would like to tail multiple files into the same window so that they are intermingled.

When I try the following:

```
tail -f logA.log logB.log
```

I get the following:

> usage: TAIL [switches] [filename]*
>      switches: [-?] display this message
>                [-n] display last n lines of each file (default 10)
>                [-f filename] keep checking filename for new lines

From the way that reads, it the format should look like:

```
tail -f logA.log -f logB.log
```

But that gives the same error. I must be missing something simple.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @DavidPostill Are you saying that this is working for you? With Cygwin?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean by "I cannot reproduce this"

Comment: `$ tail -f test.log LoremIpsum.log` gives no errors and works as expected.

Comment: That's a really weird usage message. It looks like you have some other `tail` program ahead of the cygwin one in your `$PATH`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley That was it! I didn't realize I had something else exposing that. Thanks!

Comment: Whatever it is, it must be somewhat inspired by unix `tail`, but no real unix utility would: 1. spell its own name in SHOUTY LETTERS; 2. call options "switches"; 3. Have a `-?` option (that's a globbing character eww!)

Comment: @TylerMurry Good to see you have resolved your issue. A hint for next time: `which tail` would have given the game away :)